# GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>() will return a context with no clients

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, signalr

I am trying to broadcast a message to all clients by using SignalR in a mvc application. The problem I am encountering is that when I use this code

```
var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHub>();
```

the context has no client, so the message will not be broadcasted. Here below is a simplified version of the code that I am using. I am missing something ? Thanks

The view:

```
@using System.Web.UI.WebControls
@using MyApp.Models
@model MyApp.Models.MyModel

<form class="float_left" method="post" id="form" name="form">
    <fieldset>
        Username: <br/>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Username, new { Value = Model.Username })
        <br/><br/>
        <input id="btnButton" type="button" value="Subscribe"/>
        <br/><br/>
        <div id="notificationContainer"></div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
@section scripts {
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var notification = $.connection.notificationHub;
            notification.client.addNewMessageToPage = function (message) {
                $('#notificationContainer').append('<strong>' + message + '</strong>');
            };

            $.connection.hub.start();

        });

        $("#btnButton").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/Subscribe",
                data: $('#form').serialize(),
                type: "POST"
            });
        });

    </script>
}
```

The Hub:

```
namespace MyApp.Hubs
{
    public class NotificationHub : Hub
    {
        public void Send(string message)
        {
            Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage(message);
        }
    }
}
```

The Controller:

```
namespace MyApp.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public void Subscribe()
        {
            var message = "" // get message...

            var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHub>();
            context.Clients.All.Send(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you are saying that the context says there are 0 clients and the webpage doesn't receive the message?

Comment: What you can do is:
In your  Startup file, when you `app.MapSignalR()`, you can `app.MapSignalR(new HubConfiguration
            {
        #if DEBUG
                EnableDetailedErrors = true
        #endif
            });

` This will enable  detailed errors in debigging mode. This way, you can see if the client method is actually called by opening a console in your browser. Do this and share the output, please

Comment: The hub method Send() is not called (a breakpoint is not hit), so I guess the client method is also not called: I don't get anything back in the view.

Comment: I  hope this solved your question. Best of luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the concepts a little mixed up.

The thing is that you can't call a hub method from another place in the back-end, so you can't make a call to he `Send` hub mehod but from anywhere but the connected client(in your case the website).

When you do `Context.Clients.doSomething()` you actually call the client part of `SignalR` and tell it to execute the JavaScript method `doSomething()` if it exists.

So your call from the controller should be `context.Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage(message);`

Hope this helps. Best of luck!